# I get an (AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0) when i try to load google news vector embeddings

Tags: python, flask, gensim

I have a class Featurizer that checks for the existance of an embedding_file which has word embeddings from Google news vectors and loads it when called. However when i use the class Feauturizer to load the model.

It gives an error

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\training_model.ipynb Cell 11' in <cell line: 2>()
      1 emb_file = os.path.join('D:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\embedding_file', 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin')
----> 2 featurizer = Featurizer(emb_file)

d:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\training_model.ipynb Cell 4' in Featurizer.__init__(self, embedding_file)
     11 print('INFO: Loading word vectors...')
     12 self.word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
     13     'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin',
     14     binary=True)
     16 print('INFO: Done! Using %s word vectors from pre-trained word2vec.' \
---> 17     %len(self.word2vec.vocab))

File d:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\venv\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py:735, in KeyedVectors.vocab(self)
    733 @property
    734 def vocab(self):
--> 735     raise AttributeError(
    736         "The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.\n"
    737         "Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods "
    738         ".get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.\n"
    739         "See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4"
    740     )

AttributeError: The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0.
Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val)instead.
```

See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

This is the class,

```
class Featurizer:

    def __init__(self, embedding_file):

        if not os.path.exists(embedding_file):
            raise IOError("Embeddings file does not exist: %s" %embedding_file)

        punctuation = string.punctuation
        punctuation = punctuation + "’" + "“" + "?" + "‘"
        self.punctuation = punctuation
        print('INFO: Loading word vectors...')
        self.word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
            embedding_file,
            binary=True)

        print('INFO: Done! Using %s word vectors from pre-trained word2vec.' \
            %len(self.word2vec.vocab))
```

When i try to load the embeddings using the class Featurizer

```
emb_file = os.path.join('D:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\embedding_file', 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin')
featurizer = Featurizer(emb_file)
```

Ideally, if it loaded properly. It would give a message output from the Featurizer class such as

```
emb_file = os.path.join('D:\mt 111\QuestionAnswer\embedding_file', 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin')
featurizer = Featurizer(emb_file)
```

INFO: Loading word vectors...

INFO: Done! Using 3000000 word vectors from pre-trained word2vec.

How can i go about this!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load succeeded; the failure was in your line of code that tried to report `len(self.word2vec.vocab)`.

Let me quote the error message for the reason that your code couldn't access a `.vocab` property:

> The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0. Use
> KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods
> .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.
> See
> https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

So, you can't use `.vocab` anymore, but there are several new properties listed there, like `.key_to_index` (a dict like `vocab` was) or `.index_to_key` (a list of all lookup keys – words – in the set-of-vectors).

Have you tried using any of those specific properties recommended in the error message you received, instead of `.vocab`?

Or, visiting the recommended URL, which [makes specific suggestions with before and after code examples](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#4-vocab-dict-became-key_to_index-for-looking-up-a-keys-integer-index-or-get_vecattr-and-set_vecattr-for-other-per-key-attributes) how to replace references to the no-longer-available `.vocab` attribute? Here are the relevant lines of things *not* to do (), and to do instead (), for your case:

```py
vocab_len = len(model.wv.vocab)  # 
…
vocab_len = len(model.wv)  #
```